# Azure DevOps API to manage security ACL of Variable Group

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to manage security ACL of Variable Group via API in Azure DevOps?

Couldn't find anything in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to manage security ACL of Variable Group via API in
>   Azure DevOps?

Of course sure!

In azure devops, the `namespace name` of **Variable group** is `library`. And the **namespace id** is `B7E84409-6553-448A-BBB2-AF228E07CBEB`.

*Though we did not document this, but you can catch this by **F12**. Just click on **Security**, then you would see this in the **Network**. `token` of variable group are also listed in it.*

---

After know the `namespace id` and the `token` (`library/{project id}`) of Variable group, now you could make use of this ACL management doc: [Set Access Control Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/set%20access%20control%20lists?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=5.1

"value": [
    {
      "inheritPermissions": true,
      "token": "Library/{project id}",
      "acesDictionary": {
        "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1": {
          "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1",
          "allow": 31,
          "deny": 0
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you please share screenshoot where `namespace id` and `token` can be found? can't find it(